# diff command ignoring new file in the new directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel

I added a new file in "modified directory" (in 3rd sub level folder)  and when i try to generate the patch file using the following command it appears that diff command is ignoring the new file:

```
diff –ur "original directory" "modified directory" > version1.patch
```

I appreciate your help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need `-N` flag. From `man diff`:

```
   -N  --new-file
          Treat absent files as empty.
```

When generating patches, the "standard" diff flags are `-Npur`. You've already discovered why you need `-N`; `-p` makes the patch easier for humans to read.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. -Npur worked for me and now i can see the .c file changes in the patch file. But when i try to patch it using the following command "patch -p1 < ../patch-x.y.z (patch file)" i don't see this new C file created in the corresponding sub directory.  Am i missing anything here?.

Comment: @user1427180 You have not supplied nearly enough details to answer your second question, but no: you are not missing anything, it's supposed to work, and most likely *does* work; you are probably just looking at the wrong file(s).

Comment: What i meant was: I've a created a new .c file in one of the sub directories and i can see these changes in the patch file and when i try to reapply the patch to the base version, i still don't see that "patch" command is not creating this file in the corresponding sub directory (which exists on modified directory).

Comment: @user1427180 Yes, I understand that, but my previous comment stands: you haven't supplied enough info to help you, and `patch` likely works as expected, but you are making some mistake somewhere (such as looking in the wrong place for the new file, or applying the patch in the wrong directory).

Comment: Yes. The issue was with the path.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this command,

**diff -RuN "original directory" "modified directory" > version.patch**

Comment: Which version of diff understands `-R` flag, and what does it mean?

Comment: GNU diff 3.3 (2013) does not have a `-R` option.